# Why can't I make an instance with this unparameterized type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Why is this code correct

```
instance Functor IO where -- note that IO isn't parametrized, and it's correct
    fmap f action = do
        result <- action
        return (f result)
```

but the following code has a compiler error?

```
class Print a where
    print :: a -> String

data A t = A t
instance Print A where  -- error: expecting one more argument to `A'
    print a = "abc"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the [kinds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Kind) don't match. Regular types have kind `*`, while type constructors such as `A` or `IO` have kind `* -> *`, indicating that they need a type parameter in order to return a type.

In the definition of the `Print` class, the compiler infers that since `a` is used as a plain type, it must have kind `*`. However, `Functor` works on type constructors of kind `* -> *`:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here, `f` is not used as a plain type, but as a type constructor, so it's inferred kind is `* -> *`. You can verify this with the `:kind` command in GHCi:

```
> :kind Print
Print :: * -> Constraint
> :kind Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

Answer (score 9):

When you say

```
class Print a where
   print' :: a -> String
```

You make sure that `a` has to be a type, but when you say

```
data A t = A t
```

you make `A` a type constructor - `A` isn't a type, but `A Int` is, for example. `A` is a sort of function on types, but the `a` in the Print class has to be a type value, not a type function.

You could do

```
instance Print (A Int) where
  print' a = "abc"
```

It's OK for `IO` because the `Functor` class asks for a type constructor.

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You can see that since `f a` is a type, `f` is a type constructor, just like `IO` and `A` are.
You'll be able to do

```
instance Functor A where  -- OK, A is a constructor, Functor needs one
  fmap f (A x) = A (f x)
```

and you won't be able to do

```
instance Eq IO where -- not OK - IO is a constructor and Eq needs a type
    (==) = error "this code won't compile"
```

(I've used `print'` instead of `print` to avoid clashing with the standard function `print`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try mentally (or with a text editor) filling in the types given in the class definition with the type you've used in the instance.

From:

```
class Print a where
    print :: a -> String
```

and

```
data A t = A t
```

we want

```
instance Print A
```

So, substituting `a` in the type class definition for the `A` we're saying is an instnace, we get this:

```
class Print A where
    print :: A -> String
```

Uh-oh. `A -> String` doesn't make sense as a type, since the function type arrow takes a type on the left and a type on the right, and gives you the function type. But `A` isn't a type, since you declared `A` with `data A t`; `A t` is a type for any type `t`, but `A` is a *type constructor*. It can make a type if you apply it to a type, but `A` itself is something different. So you can make `A t` into an instance of `Print`, but not `A` itself.

So why did `instance Functor IO` work? Lets look at the class definition:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Now lets try substituting `IO` for `f`:

```
class Functor IO where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

The `IO`s end up applied to type parameters, so it all works out. Here we'd run into problems if we tried to make a concrete type like `Int` or `A t` an instance of `Functor`.